# Query "Standard View, with Expanded Recurring Events" doesn't show all items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, list-view

For Calendar list, I have created a view with type of "Standard View, with Expanded Recurring Events".
This view is used to show each instance of a recurring event. So if there is an event with let's say 10 times recurring, this view will show 10 items in its view.
But when I used to query and display (JSOM) through code, it has only one item. Is this the default behavior of "Standard View, with Expanded Recurring Events" view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the event item is only one. However, it spans those timings which are mentioned in recurrence. If you go into List ribbon settings, you may find a view named "All Events". Click on this view and you should be able to see only one item for this recurrence.

Comment: Great @Nadeem Yousuf. What you are telling is right. So is there anyway to get all recurring data by querying?

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban, yes, there is a field named `RecurrenceData` which stores the data in xml format.

Comment: Thinking about lazy way rather than querying XML. Is it possible to export the view to different list. Then work will be so easy..?

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban, not sure what you are talking about. Getting recurrencedata is similar to getting the value of a `Title` filed. Something like `listitem.get_item('RecurrenceData')`.

Comment: Yes understood. We can get RecurrenceData as you mentioned. But it will be in XML format. So I worry about we need another querying part to retract data ..